# Differences between the conformal group and the Schrödinger group?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, maxwell-equations, galilean-relativity

Facts:

1. The Maxwell (free) equations (4d) are invariant under the 15 dimensional conformal group.
2. The free Schrödinger equation in 3d is invariant under the 15 dimensional group "called" [Schrödinger group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_group) (15 dimensional too in 4d).

What is the relationship between those two groups (are they the same or there is any subtle difference?)?

Comment: Do you mean the free Schrodinger *equation* is invariant...?

Comment: Did you read the last section of the Wikipedia article you linked?

Comment: The conformal group is simple; the Schrödinger group is not (it is not even semi-simple).  They are different groups.

Comment: And also note that the Schrödinger group under which the 3d Schrödinger equation is invariant is only 12-dimensional, not 15-dimensional. This is not clear in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the OP question

> What is the relationship between those two groups (are they the same or there is any subtle difference?)?

is offered by Niederer, U. in his Helv.Phys.Acta article called *"The connection between the Schrödinger group and the conformal group"*, Vol. 47, p.119 (found at http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-114561 and freely download-able). From this paper you find the reference [3] which is another "bite" (same journal, but Vol. 46) at this topic by the famous Asim Barut:

*"Conformal Group -> Schrödinger Group -> Dynamical Group -
The Maximal Kinematical Group of the Massive Schrödinger
Particle"*

(the the direct link is http://doi.org/10.5169/seals-114492).

I would first read Barut's work, then Niederer's.